# How can I get the URL of an internet shortcut (.url)?

Tags: vb.net, url, shortcut-file

My client has some internet shortcuts `(*.url)` on his desktop and I want to get their URL through a VB application and use them as variables.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [sample on MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Identifying-and-Resolving-ca0dfce8) for `*.lnk` and `*.appref-ms`-files.

But seems to work for `*.url`-files too.

Quote from the site:

> To check if a file is a shortcut and to resolve a shortcut path, the
>   COM Library *Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation* is used. This
>   library is added to the References of the Visual Studio project.

Code:

```
Public Function IsShortcut(strPath As String) As Boolean 
    If Not File.Exists(strPath) Then 
        Return False 
    End If 

    Dim directory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath) 
    Dim strFile As String = Path.GetFileName(strPath) 

    Dim shell As Shell32.Shell = New Shell32.Shell() 
    Dim folder As Shell32.Folder = shell.NameSpace(directory) 
    Dim folderItem As Shell32.FolderItem = folder.ParseName(strFile) 

    If folderItem IsNot Nothing Then 
        Return folderItem.IsLink 
    End If 

    Return False 
End Function

Public Function ResolveShortcut(strPath As String) As String 
    If IsShortcut(strPath) Then 
        Dim directory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath) 
        Dim strFile As String = Path.GetFileName(strPath) 

        Dim shell As Shell32.Shell = New Shell32.Shell() 
        Dim folder As Shell32.Folder = shell.NameSpace(directory) 
        Dim folderItem As Shell32.FolderItem = folder.ParseName(strFile) 

        Dim link As Shell32.ShellLinkObject = folderItem.GetLink 

        Return link.Path 
    End If 

    Return String.Empty 
End Function
```

Comment: Do I have to import something first?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the COM Library _Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation_. The `File.*` and `Path.*` functions are from `System.IO.`-namespace